# subtract values in column 1 if column 2 is the same

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file on the following format:

```
0.019059000     15150000000
0.037088000     15150000000
0.035007000     15150000001
0.047622000     15150000001
0.053359000     15150000002
0.060405000     15150000002
0.068598000     15150000003
0.081587000     15150000003
```

I would like to subtract column 1 when column 2 is the same. For example for the input file, i would like to have something like this:

```
0.018029 15150000000
0.012615 15150000001
0.007046 15150000002
0.012989 15150000003
```

All the values on the column 2 on the input file go in pairs for example 
15150000000 exists only two times, 15150000001 exists only two times etc.

Any help is more than welcome!

Comment: Are the same values in column2 always adjacent?

Comment: not necessary. It can jump some values. so from 15150000003 the next can be 15150000004 or 15150000005

Comment: I mean in the file, do they occupy adjacent lines?

Comment: yes i sorted the file based on column 2.

Comment: If the file is unsorted, do you subtract smaller from bigger or second from first or what?

Comment: Yes if the file is unsorted, i would like to not have negative values and subtract smaller from bigger since the first column represent time in seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue! (without error checking.)

```
$ awk 'p==$2 {print $1-pv,p} {p=$2; pv=$1}' file

0.018029 15150000000
0.012615 15150000001
0.007046 15150000002
0.012989 15150000003
```

for unsorted but again double records for the same key

```
$ awk '$2 in a {print $1-a[$2],$2; delete a[$2]; next} {a[$2]=$1}' file

0.018029 15150000000
0.012615 15150000001
0.007046 15150000002
0.012989 15150000003
```

if the second value not always larger than the first one and you want the absolute difference

```
$ awk 'function abs(x) {return x<0?-x:x}
       $2 in a {print abs($1-a[$2]),$2; delete a[$2]; next} 
               {a[$2]=$1}' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot karakfa! It seems that it's working as expected! One more fast question just from curiocity.. Doesn't seems to work if the file is not sorted first based on column 2. Is there a way to have the same result even if the file is unsorted?

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk, subtracts smaller from bigger:

```
$ awk '{
    if($2 in a) {                              # if another $2 already met
        print ((s=$1-a[$2])>0?s:-s),$2         # subtract smaller from bigger
        delete a[$2]                           # delete to save memory
    } else 
        a[$2]=$1                               # else store $2
}' <(shuf file)                                # shuf file to demo random order
                                               # replace with just the file name
```

A sample output (due to `shuf`randomness):

```
0.007046 15150000002
0.018029 15150000000
0.012615 15150000001
0.012989 15150000003
```

Comment: you can replace `a[$2]-$1` with `-s`

Comment: @karakfa Good point, thanks. That's what taking a too long nap does to a person... :D.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
awk '{a[$2] = $1 - a[$2]} END {for (b in a) print a[b], b}' file
```

---

Ah, I see you have values in **pairs**. Go with karakfa's answer then.